# C# async file(...) operation, Asynch itself how to

Tags: c#

Its few months i am into the C#... and i am listening Asynchronous ... operation stuff... though concept sounds easy i am finding it difficult to understand it.

What i would like to try is to send huge HTTP request/file and write it on server end using asynch operation once its compete read the file from this location and take it to other place.

Can some one please guide me to some nice Asynchronous tutorials where it would be easy for me to visualize and understand how to and what it does ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a sample here: [Making Asynchronous Requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wf6409%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) of how to use HttpRequest asynchronously.